# How to handle window scroll event in Angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I can't seem to be able to capture the Window scroll event.
On several sites I found code similar to this:

```
@HostListener("window:scroll", [])
onWindowScroll() {
  console.log("Scrolling!");
}
```

The snippets often come from version 2. This doesn't seem to work (anymore?) in Angular 4.2.2. If I replace "window:scroll" with "window:touchmove" for example, then then touchmove event is handled fine.

Does anyone know what I'm missing? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Probably your `document` isn't scrolling, but a `div` inside it is. The scroll event only bubbles up to the `window` if it's called from `document`. Also if you capture the event from `document` and call something like `stopPropagation`, you will not receive the event in `window`.

If you want to capture all the scroll events inside your application, which will also be from tiny scrollable containers, you have to use the default `addEventListener` method with `useCapture` set to `true`.

This will fire the event when it goes down the `DOM`, instead of the bubble stage. Unfortunately, and quite frankly a big miss, angular does not provide an option to pass in the event listener options, so you have to use the `addEventListener`:

```
export class WindowScrollDirective {

    ngOnInit() {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scroll, true); //third parameter
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.scroll, true);
    }

    scroll = (event): void => {
      //handle your scroll here
      //notice the 'odd' function assignment to a class field
      //this is used to be able to remove the event listener
    };

}
```

Now this is not all there is to it, because all major browsers (except IE and Edge, obviously) have implemented the new `addEventListener` spec, which makes it possible to pass an object as [third parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

With this object you can mark an event listener as `passive`. This is a recommend thing to do on an event which fires a lot of time, which can interfere with UI performance, like the scroll event. To implement this, you should first check if the current browser supports this feature. On the mozilla.org they've posted a method `passiveSupported`, with which you can check for browser support. You can only use this though, when you are sure you are not going to use `event.preventDefault()`

Before I show you how to do that, there is another performance feature you could think of. To prevent change detection from running (the `DoCheck` gets called every time something async happens within the zone. Like an event firing), you should run your event listener outside the zone, and only enter it when it's really necessary. Soo, let's combine all these things:

```
export class WindowScrollDirective {

    private eventOptions: boolean|{capture?: boolean, passive?: boolean};

    constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {}

    ngOnInit() {            
        if (passiveSupported()) { //use the implementation on mozilla
            this.eventOptions = {
                capture: true,
                passive: true
            };
        } else {
            this.eventOptions = true;
        }
        this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
            window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scroll, <any>this.eventOptions);
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.scroll, <any>this.eventOptions);
        //unfortunately the compiler doesn't know yet about this object, so cast to any
    }

    scroll = (): void => {
        if (somethingMajorHasHappenedTimeToTellAngular) {
           this.ngZone.run(() => {
               this.tellAngular();
           });
        }
    };   
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems to work as expected! I think the problem is indeed that the document itself does not scroll in my situation.

Comment: @Robert I've updated my answer a bit more with additional info :)

Comment: Is the content inside the listener in the second code block correlated to intercepting the events? Furthermore, how do iche the direction of the scroll?

Comment: Directly accessing `window` or `document` DOM objects in Angular is not recommended as due to the inherit Angular's change detection. Moreover, `scroll` events are blacklisted in ngzone so you need to implement it outside zones.

Comment: That's exactly what I said in my answer :)

Comment: Would it make sense to create a scroll event listener in the app.module and subscribe to changes in the directives?  That way we don't have several event listeners where just one would do

Comment: one question, is `@HostListener` obsolete or what? for angular7 maybe

Comment: @mkb it's not obsolete. It's very useful. It just doesn't support the use of the native event options yet.

Comment: @PierreDuc , Oh I see, thank you for the explanation

Comment: What if you want to pass a string or something to the method with the template reference (Viewchild of the view section) so that it knows when you scroll down, to move to the next template ref?

Comment: I tried using this in a component that has a couple of instances on the page, and it looks like only one of them is working. What's the best way to adapt this to work for multiple components on one page that need to do something (eg. hide themselves) on scroll?

Answer (score 40):

If you happen to be ***using Angular Material***, you can do this:

```
import { ScrollDispatchModule } from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';
```

In Ts:

```
import { ScrollDispatcher } from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';

  constructor(private scrollDispatcher: ScrollDispatcher) {    
    this.scrollDispatcher.scrolled().subscribe(x => console.log('I am scrolling'));
  }
```

And in Template:

```
<div cdkScrollable>
  <div *ngFor="let one of manyToScrollThru">
    {{one}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Reference: https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems to work as expected for me!

Comment: How do u get the scroll direction and offset in this case. The emitted event seems to be blank.

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari - See: `measureScrollOffset` in [https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/api](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/api).  Could combine with Rxjs `pairWise` in an observable to see which direction you are scrolling.  There might be a more direct way, but this is a solution.

Comment: I see what you are trying to suggest. But the `measureScrollOffset`  method is not supported on `scrollDispatcher`. It is only supported on `cdk-scrollable` directive. Still, I might make something out of your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari measureScrollOffset is what is available in the lambda value: subscribe(x => console.log(x.measureScrolloffset('top'))); as an example.

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari You have worked out a solution to retrieve the offset ?

Comment: In my case, in an Angular Material application, it appears I do not need to import the module. I have no such `import { ScrollingModule } from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';` statement.

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari I could finally get the offset with the following: `this.scrollSubscription = this.scrollDispatcher.scrolled().subscribe((cdk: CdkScrollable | void) => { this.scrollY = (cdk as CdkScrollable).getElementRef().nativeElement.scrollTop || 0; console.log('Scroll: ' + this.scrollY); });`

Comment: Now I wonder how to produce a scroll reading event from a resize caught event.

Answer (score 21):

I am not allowed to comment yet. @PierreDuc your answer is spot on, except as @Robert said the document does not scroll. I modified your answer a little bit to use the event sent by the listener and then monitor the source element.

```
 ngOnInit() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scrollEvent, true);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.scrollEvent, true);
  }

  scrollEvent = (event: any): void => {
    const n = event.srcElement.scrollingElement.scrollTop;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for including the `event` parameter.  The accepted answer is kinda useless without it

Comment: Do you know how I can access the scope of the component from within the function?

Answer (score 6):

In angular 8, implement this code, in my case it worked correctly to change the color of the navbar using scroll...
your template:

```
<div class="level" (scroll)="scrolling($event)"  [ngClass]="{'level-trans': scroll}">
<!-- your template -->
</div>
```

your .ts

```
export class HomeNavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  scroll:boolean=false;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scrolling, true)
  }
  scrolling=(s)=>{
    let sc = s.target.scrollingElement.scrollTop;
    console.log();
    if(sc >=100){this.scroll=true}
    else{this.scroll=false}
  }
```

your css

```
.level{
    width: 100%;
    height: 57px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0,0,0.7);
    background: transparent;
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    transition: .8s all ease;
}
.level-trans{
    background: whitesmoke;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just in case I was looking to capture the wheel action over an element that had no way to scroll since it didn't have a scroll bar ...

So, what I needed was this:

```
@HostListener('mousewheel', ['$event']) 
onMousewheel(event) {
     console.log(event)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

an alternative with `window` in `HostListener` :
use `body`

in `core.d.ts`:

The global target names that can be used to prefix an event name are
`document:`, `window:` and `body:`

```
@HostListener('body:scroll', ['$event']) onScroll(event: any) {
    console.log(event);

  }
```