# @HostListener is not working with scroll in Angular 4.2.3

Tags: javascript, angular

you check the below code sample, all other events are working fine except `scroll`

```js
import { Component, HostListener, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Route, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { MovieDBService } from '../services/movie-db.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-popular',
  templateUrl: './popular.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./popular.component.css']
})

export class PopularComponent implements OnInit {

  movies: any[];

  constructor(
    private dbservice: MovieDBService,
    private router: Router,
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getMovies('popular');
  }

  @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event']) onWindowScroll(event: Event): void {
    console.log('scrolled');
  }

  getMovies(type) {
    this.dbservice.getMovies(type).subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.movies = res.results.map(movie => {
        movie.poster_path = `http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${movie.poster_path}`;
        movie.backdrop_path = `http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${movie.backdrop_path}`;
        movie.overview = movie.overview.substr(0, 100) + '...';
        return movie;
      });
    });
  }

  goToMovieDetails(movie) {
    this.router.navigate(['/movie', movie.id]);
  }



}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are scrolling the body of your page and  not scrolling into an element ?

Comment: try with `document:scroll`, for me it works just fine.

Comment: @Ploppy yes, scrolling on body only

Comment: @YordanNikolov tried no luck

Comment: It should work (http://plnkr.co/edit/DKGkD8sPAyJpfw3LTM43?p=preview) try updating to 4.2.4

Comment: @Ploppy its working on `plnkr` but not in my repo, tried with upgrading to 4.2.4

Comment: I'm having this issue as well, but I found this answer, and it worked for me - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44516017/how-to-handle-window-scroll-event-in-angular-4