# scroll event not firing on element div

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have a div inside an Angular component's template. On the div i am trying to get scroll position of a div.

```
   <div class="data-input" (scroll)="onScroll($event)">Accepted Qty....</div>
```

html element looks like this.

in the TS file i have a function

```
 onScroll(event) {
    console.log(event);
}
```

but this function is not hitting.

i already tried

```
@HostListener('scroll', ['$event'])
 onScroll(event) {  ...}
```

but this works when page scrolls. I want to trigger the scroll event when an html element (div) scrolls.

Comment: Might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44516017/how-to-handle-window-scroll-event-in-angular-4

Comment: but i am not trying to get window scroll. i am trying to get element scroll.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Do you see the problem in other browsers?

Comment: i am using chrome. haven't looked into any other browser yet.

Comment: And on what kind of computer?

Comment: windows machine

Comment: Can you catch other events for that div (e.g. `mousedown`)?

Comment: i can easily catch click event and other regular stuff. I am sure mousedown will also work.

Comment: just double checked,
mousedown works

Comment: You may want to comment on [this Angular issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17015). I tried Günter's plunker and did not see the console output.

Comment: sure ill do that.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to do it via `ElementRef` and `Renderer`. I drafted a separate scrollable component for you to demonstrate the concept:

```
import {Component, OnInit, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
import {ElementRef, Renderer2} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-scroll',
  template: '<div>Accepted Qty....</div>'
})

export class MyScrollComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  onScrollListener: Function;

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.onScrollListener = 
        this.renderer.listen(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'scroll', this.onScroll);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.onScrollListener();
  }

  onScroll(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```

Comment: the div element in my case is inside other elements.

Comment: And I see no problem to use it in a way `<span> Hello <my-scroll/> world </span>`. Also you may create a wrapper from MyScroll component to provide independent contents like: `<my-scroll> <Hello/> world! </my-scroll>`. The second approach requires some additional code. Also you may build a Directive... It's just a concept, anyway, and in my project I preffer to use `Renderer.lesten` instead of `HostListener`.