# How to push item in array when scroll position reaches to bottom?

Tags: javascript, angular

Could you please tell me how to push item in the array when scroll position reaches to bottom? I make a `directive` where I added the scroll event. I want to add new items in the array when the user moves scroll to `bottom`.

Here is my code :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m1sgsm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fscroll.directive.ts

```
import { Directive,OnInit ,OnDestroy,NgZone} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appScroll]'
})
export class ScrollDirective implements OnInit ,OnDestroy{

  constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) { }

  ngOnInit() {
       this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
            window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scroll, true);
        });//third parameter
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.scroll, true);
    }

    scroll = (): void => {
      console.log('ddd')

    };

}
```

I take help from this link : 
[How to handle window scroll event in Angular 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44516017/how-to-handle-window-scroll-event-in-angular-4)

Can we run `scrolling` code outside the `angular` and when reaches to bottom and added an item in the array then tell `angular`.

Comment: You should use HostListener instead, and I'm not sure if you're asking how to push items into an array or tell if you've hit bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could [update your scroll function](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gpmrcb?file=src/app/scroll.directive.ts) to check if the target's `scrollTop` value is equal to the target's `scrollHeight - offsetHeight` value.

```
  scroll = (e): void => {
    //e.target.scrollTop = current scroll position
    //e.target.scrollHeight - e.target.offsetHeight = to calculate the bottom. equivalent to scrollTopMax in FF
    if (e.target.scrollTop == e.target.scrollHeight - e.target.offsetHeight) {
      console.log('You reached the bottom!');
      //Push item into array
    }
  };
```

To push an item into an array take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) for the array.push method