# Sticky header for my table in Angular 5

Tags: angular, scroll, element

I'm trying to implement a sticky header for my table in Angular 5.

these are the links I reffered.
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_navbar_sticky

I need something similar to this but my usage is I'm placing the scrollable content in a Scrollable div. hence my on scroll values remain same they wont change. I'm able to trigger the onscroll event

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<div class="body">
<div class="header">
  <h2>Scroll Down</h2>
 <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
 </div>

 <div id="navbar">
   <a class="active" href="javascript:void(0)">Home</a>
   <a href="javascript:void(0)">News</a>
   <a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact</a>
 </div>

<div class="content">
  <h3>Sticky Navigation Example</h3>
  <p>The navbar will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position. 
 </p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum 
  definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut 
  quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert 
  laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no 
  molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum 
  definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut 
  quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert 
  laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no 
  molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  <script>
  window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

 var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
 var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

 var navbar1 = document.getElementsByClassName("body");
 var sticky1 = navbar1[0].offsetTop;

 function myFunction() {
 console.log("01 --> " + sticky1);
  console.log("02 --> " + window.pageYOffset);
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
   navbar.classList.add("sticky")
   } else {
   navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
 }
 </script>

 </body>
 </html>`
```

this is how my code is.

I used this link to convert the JS code to NG2

[How to handle window scroll event in Angular 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44516017/how-to-handle-window-scroll-event-in-angular-4)

Comment: Can you provide a plunker\stacblitz or a codesandbox ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kw7q12q9zr) with an example that should work pretty much everywhere. In the example that is shown in the demo, I'm using a directive that is responsible for setting the `position:fixed` property on the navbar and appropriate `margin-top` on the content, so that the content is not overlapped, in the moment of 'fixation'.

You can also check out the `position:sticky` css property, but it wont work in some older browser. I hope this is helpful :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but my scenario is that the scroll action appears inside a scrollable div. that is where the sticky wont work. Hope you understood the problem :)

Comment: Can you check out again the demo link, i extended it, so that there is now also a div with scrollable content.

Comment: Thank you ! this is what I was looking. I changed scroll-box.component.html and it works.                                                                                                
                                        <div class="immutable-content">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum.</div>
  <div class="immutable-header">Immutable header</div>

Answer (score 3):

You probably can utilize my library "[angular-sticky-things](https://github.com/w11k/angular-sticky-things)" for this. It is available via npm:

```
npm install @w11k/angular-sticky-things
```

Or just take a closer look at my source code - it is not that much. The interesting part is [here](https://github.com/w11k/angular-sticky-things/blob/master/projects/angular-sticky-things/src/lib/sticky-thing.directive.ts). I think it is very important to move such stuff into a re-useable directive.

Please let me know if the desired feature of sticky thing inside a div instead of a window works out of the box - otherwise, I'll just add the feature for you.

Comment: Hi, i tried your library, its awesome, only problem that i am facing is header doesnt remains the same size as the tbody rows are

Comment: Are you using a spacer element? If possible, please provide a stack blitz of the problem and I'll fix it.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking time to reply, 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a7q2ro 
here is sample, just scroll down the table and you will know the problem, please dnt change my css as its dependent on another thing

Comment: actually what happens is, when i scroll down `thead` squeeze itself, but `tbody` has expanded as per data

Comment: Ah I can see your problem now. The Table is special. Since the width of the td/th is determined by the columns content. You probably need to apply a fixed width per column. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8afvgc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: i have this big Table it will contain price values like 9.54879364544654, so i can not fix width,