# How to add a scroll top button in jhipster?

Tags: jhipster

How to create a "scroll top" or "go back top" button in Jhipster.

When I want to access the navbar, I want a quick action to avoid scrolling all the page up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my way to have a button "go to top" on the side of the page.
The button is visible when you are not at the top.

`src/main/webapp/app/layouts/scroll-top/scroll-top.component.ts`

```
ngOnInit() {
  // When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, show the button
  window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scroll, true);
}

scroll = (): void => {
  // handle your scroll here
  // notice the 'odd' function assignment to a class field
  // this is used to be able to remove the event listener
  // console.log('scroll', document.body.scrollTop, document.documentElement.scrollTop);
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    document.getElementById('goTopBtn').style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('goTopBtn').style.display = 'none';
  }
};

// When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
goTop() {
  document.body.scrollTop = 0; // For Safari
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0; // For Chrome, Firefox, IE and Opera
}
```

`src/main/webapp/app/layouts/scroll-top/scroll-top.component.html`

```
    <button (click)="goTop()" id="goTopBtn" title="Go to top" class="btn btn-secondary">Top</button>
```

`src/main/webapp/app/layouts/scroll-top/scroll-top.component.scss`
(only positioning, the styling is in the html with bootstrap classes)

```
#goTopBtn {
    display: none;
    /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed;
    /* Fixed/sticky position */
    bottom: 20px;
    /* Place the button at the bottom of the page */
    right: 30px;
    /* Place the button 30px from the right */
    z-index: 99;
    /* Make sure it does not overlap */
}
```

`src/main/webapp/app/layouts/main/main.component.html`
(add after the `navbar`)

```
<jhi-scroll-top></jhi-scroll-top>
```

`src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts`
(add `ScrollTopComponent` in `declarations`)

```
declarations: [JhiMainComponent, NavbarComponent, ErrorComponent, PageRibbonComponent, ActiveMenuDirective, FooterComponent, ScrollTopComponent],
```

### Left TODO :

- I18N/Glyphicon.
- Check responsiveness and browser compatibility

### Thank you

- pierreduc in  [How to handle window scroll event in Angular 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44516017/how-to-handle-window-scroll-event-in-angular-4)
- https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_scroll_to_top.asp