# Angular 7 scroll event does not fire

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

For implementing a spy nav bar in my Angular app in a MatDialog component. 
I implemented a directive to spy for the scroll event using

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
```

I also tried `'scroll'` as event name. But the event does not seem to fire. I tried several approaches, e. g. by using the HostListener directly in the dialog component, by using the JavaScript `window.onscroll()` function and the rxjs `fromEvent()` function but without success.

Trying other css events (e. g. `window:click`) work fine.
I also tried it in a "normal" component that is not displayed as a dialog but the event is not fired there either.

What could be the cause of this behaviour?

Comment: It would be better if you produce a StackBlitz Example

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason for this behaviour is that angular material blocks the scroll event.

I solved it like this:

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {

    const content = document.querySelector('.mat-dialog-container');
    const scroll$ = fromEvent(content, 'scroll').pipe(map(() => content));

    scroll$.subscribe(element => {
      // do whatever
    });
  }
```

Comment: a case where angular is slightly over engineered, nevertheless you're a life saver, thank you for this!

Comment: from where that `fromEvent` coming from?

Comment: fromEvent is a rxjs method that turns an event into an observable sequence: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/fromevent

Answer (score 26):

Here is an alternative [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44516017/how-to-handle-window-scroll-event-in-angular-4/54005183#54005183) which works rather well.

In short:

```
ngOnInit() {
    // Add an event listener to window
    // Window can be defined in the pollyfiles.ts as: 
    // if (window) {
    //    (window as any).global = window;
    // }
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scroll, true); //third parameter
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.scroll, true);
}

scroll = (event: any): void => {
  // Here scroll is a variable holding the anonymous function 
  // this allows scroll to be assigned to the event during onInit
  // and removed onDestroy
  // To see what changed:
  const number = event.srcElement.scrollTop;
  console.log(event);
  console.log('I am scrolling ' + number);
};
```

Comment: took me 3 hours to find a working solution. Shot mate. Appreciated

Comment: @AaronMatthews  Pleasure :)

Comment: This is the only code that works out of the 20 other snippets i've tried

Answer (score 1):

Try this...No need to do anything with html.

```
import { Component, OnInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event']) getScrollHeight(event) {
   console.log(window.pageYOffset, event);
}
```

Comment: So this is a directive right? Do I just add it to the elemnt where I need to listen to? I tried so, but with "window:scroll" as event, it is not getting listened to. Do I add it to app.component.html itself?