# Angular material table detect Scroll

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk, angular-material-table, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

I'm using Angular Material Table and want to detect when user scrolls the table. For this, I'm using `cdkScrollable`.

`app-my-component`:

```
<table mat-table cdkScrollable [dataSource]="dataSource">

constructor(private scrollDispatcher: ScrollDispatcher) {
    this.scrollDispatcher.scrolled().subscribe(x => console.log('I am scrolling'));
}
```

This works fine when `app-my-component` is part of the root app-component.

But it does not work when `app-my-component` is inside `mat-tab`.

```
<mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="tabChanged($event)">
    <mat-tab>
      <ng-template mat-tab-label>
        <span>My Component</span>
      </ng-template>

      <app-my-component></app-my-component>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

The height of table in `app-my-component` is restricted to height of mat-tab. So the scrollbar appears inside the mat-tab.

How can I make it work when `app-my-component` is inside `mat-tab`?

Comment: Can you please recreate this issue in stackblitz?

Comment: Try the accepted solution from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53188426/angular-7-scroll-event-does-not-fire

Comment: is this about mat-tab or mat-table?