# Is there a predefined DOM Event object for scroll event?

Tags: typescript, dom-events, strong-typing

I'm creating an event handler for a component in Angular.

The problem I'm having is right now is: I can't find a typed event for scroll, therefore in the handler's argument I must use `any`.

I see there are some other typed DOM Event like `MouseEvent`, `DragEvent`...Is there something like `ScrollEvent` ?

My sample code:

*component.html*

```
<div (scroll)="onScroll($event)">
    ...more elements here
</div>
```

*component.ts*

```
onScroll(scrollEvent: any) {
    // When debugging here, scrollEvent is of type "Event"
    // but if I declare "scrollEvent: Event", I must use "(e.target as any).offsetHeight" 
    // because "Event" doesn't have offsetHeight property
    let offsetHeight = e.target.offsetHeight;
    ...more logic here
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44516017/how-to-handle-window-scroll-event-in-angular-4/44516191

Comment: @MuhFred: thanks, but the handling is working perfectly. My question is about the type of the argument, because using `any` doesn't provide type-safety.