# How to auto hide bsDatepicker on scroll in ng-template of modal

Tags: angular, bootstrap-datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

I want bsDatepicker can auto-hide on scroll inside modal which wraps by ng-template.

It's the same problem as https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/5390

But I still can't solve my problem.

There's my code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2swahw

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem may be due to the scroll event not happening on the `window`, rather it is appearing on a `div` instead.

I played around with the stackblitz that you created and here is, what worked for me.

```
  constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.hideDialog, true);
  }

  hideDialog = (): void => {
    this.datepicker.hide();
  };
```

I recommend that you read the answers here, it will help You make your code more robust and increase UI performance.

[How to handle window scroll event in Angular 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44516017/how-to-handle-window-scroll-event-in-angular-4/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply but your code working open component inside modal, how can I solve with open ng-template inside modal?

Comment: @OwenLin I see you updated your slackblitz so it's working fine now? 
I think for ng-template it was not working because we didn't have the reference for `datepicker`. I see you have selected it using ` document.querySelector`.

Comment: Yes, it's working now. I read another post says ViewChild is working in a component not ng-template. Someone offers a solution to use document.querySelector. But ngx-bootstrap needs to upgrade to 8.0.0 otherwise you'll face "Cannot reference null object of "removeChild"..."