# Pagination on scroll Angular Firestore

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

I need help with firestore angular. I want to implement pagination on scroll. I can't figure out how to do it.

I did it as a button, when the button is clicked, it shows as many posts as I want, but with the help of scroll I can’t do it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44516017/how-to-handle-window-scroll-event-in-angular-4) has a breakdown of how people have implemented triggering logic on the scroll event in Angular.

It is hard to be more specific without more details about your Angular project.